# How to make an api request after previous api request completed in ionic

Tags: angular, wordpress, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am making 3 api post requests to the wordpress api:
2 api post requestes to wp-json/wp/v2/media so upload images
1 api post request to wp-json/wp/v2/posts to save the source_url (which was retrieved from the previous 2 api post requests) to a new post that is created.

The last api is dependable on the first 2 api request calls and shouldn't be executed until those 2 apis are complete as I need the values from their callback to be used in my last api request call.

My current problem is that all my api request calls are running at the same time and therefore the values are I need from the first 2 api call requests are not ready and they are showing as empty in my last api request call.

```
submitStory() {

    this.beforeImageUpload = this.transfer.create();
    this.beforeImageUpload.upload(this.beforeImageURL, this.url + "wp-json/wp/v2/media", {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxx",
        "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\'before-image.jpg\'"
      }
    })
    .then((data)=>{
      return JSON.parse(data.response);
    })
    .then((data) => {
      this.before_image = data.source_url;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })

    this.afterImageUpload = this.transfer.create();
    this.afterImageUpload.upload(this.afterImageURL, this.url + "wp-json/wp/v2/media", {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxx",
        "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\'after-image.jpg\'"
      }
    })
    .then((data)=>{
      return JSON.parse(data.response);
    })
    .then((data) => {
      this.after_image = data.source_url;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })

    let postData = {
      "title": capital_letter(this.firstname + " " + this.lastname + "'s Story"),
      "content": this.description,
      "before_image": this.before_image,
      "after_image": this.after_image
    }

    this.http.post(this.url + "wp-json/wp/v2/stories", postData, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxx",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    this.router.navigate([`stories`]);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call Request 2nd when 1st gets completed.

For example:

```
firstRequest(){
    this.http.post("url", firstReqData, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxx",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.secondRequest(pass, your, data, to, second); // call this function to call your second request when first get completed
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
 }


secondRequest(get, your, data, to, second){ // get data to send it in 2nd request
    this.http.post("url", secondReqData, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxx",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
 }
```